# Adobe Air - Textfield with Chinese characters

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, globalization, font-embedding

I've a contact form that needs to support Chinese characters. Right now if I enter Chinese text nothing shows up. (Not even the empty box placeholder)

How to handle Chinese characters in an Adobe Air dynamic textfield?

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 2):

Can' you just embed the font you are using to include the Chinese characters you need?

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest a font that is supporting these characters? I tried various without any success. @Marty Wallace Do you think that could result in any problems?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Chinese Fonts, but googling it I found this site: http://www.clearchinese.com/resources/fonts.htm The more glyphs you have in your swf the bigger it will be, which means slightly longer load times. I would suggest you only include the character sets you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thats a few years late... but just use "_sans" as font. If you develop for mobile, it will use the device fonts, which support everything, but look differently from device to device.